# Sobolev estimates on domain with boundary

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Could someone point me to a reference for the proof of the following Sobolev estimate
$$
\|u\|_{L^{2 d /(d-2)}(\Omega)} \leqslant C(\|f\|_{L^{2 d /(d+2)}(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{(\partial\Omega)})
$$
for all $u \in W^{2,2 d /(d+2)}(\Omega)$ such that $\Delta u=f$ and $g=u$ on $\partial \Omega$, and $d>2$ $\Omega$ is a smooth domain of $\mathbf R^d$?
Thanks in advance to anyone who could offer help.

Comment: Could you clarify the norm for $g$ that you want?

Comment: Cross-post from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695311

Comment: The norm of $g$ could be $W^{(3d-2)/2d, 2d/(d+2)}$ or simply $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$. I'm just interested in the idea of the proof, thanks.

Comment: This question is maybe not totally research level, but since you are a new contributor, a few hints: Use the Lax-Milgram theorem + a trace extension operator $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$ + Sobolev embedding. All of these can be found in any text book on functional analysis methods for elliptic second order PDEs, for example in the one by Brezis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking if there's another way to proof this estimates directly. The classical method, like you said, does not applied with the case $g\in W^{(3d-2)/2d, 2d/(d+2)}(\partial \Omega)$. If there's a way using the construction of a parametrix in local coordinates.